# How to add custom search by date range in jQuery DataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I use DataTables 1.10.6 (https://datatables.net/) on ASP.NET MVC project.

There I have table with variable columns count (depends on table, defined on load). For some columns I have simple text search, for other - drop-down values search. And for one column (with dates) I need to provide date range search.
I try this solution https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html but it runs after table initialization (for every table and for same column with index `3`) while I need it only when value in input field is changed.

I try this code (from example):

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
        var min = parseInt( $('#min').val(), 10 );
        var max = parseInt( $('#max').val(), 10 );
        var age = parseFloat( data[3] ) || 0; // use data for the age column

        if ( ( isNaN( min ) && isNaN( max ) ) ||
             ( isNaN( min ) && age <= max ) ||
             ( min <= age   && isNaN( max ) ) ||
             ( min <= age   && age <= max ) )
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);
```

But this code does not depends on table and when I have two tables on same page I don't know how to take input value from current table.
I need custom search function that can take min/max values, column index (where to search) and works per table.

I need something like this:

```
function DatarangeColumnCustomSearch(searchQuery) {
    if (searchQuery != undefined) {
        var startDate = Date.parse(searchQuery[0]),
            endDate = Date.parse(searchQuery[1]),
            comparativeDate = Date.parse(rowData[*...current column...*]);
        if (startDate <= comparativeDate && comparativeDate < endDate.addDays(1)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}


table.api().columns('.whereSearchForDaterange').every(function() {
    var column = this;
    $('input.datarangeFilter', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
        var dates = this.value.split(' - ');
        column.DatarangeColumnCustomSearch(dates).draw();
    });
});
```

Please, help!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but maybe this answer can help someone else.

Notice that in order to solve your issue regarding having two or more DataTables in the same page, you need to include inside `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push` this:

```
// Don't filter on anything other than "myTable" ("myTable" is the name of your DataTable that you want to be filtered)
    if ( settings.nTable.id !== 'myTable' ) {
        return true;
    }
```

I'm using **moment.js** to handle and validate the dates fetched using regular textboxes, but you can use **jQuery UI's DatePicker** to get them if you prefer:

```js
/* Custom filtering function which will search data in column four between two values */
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
        
        if ( settings.nTable.id !== 'example' ) {
            return true;
        }
        
                var from = moment($('#from').val(), "YYYY/MM/DD"); 
        var to = moment($('#to').val(), "YYYY/MM/DD"); 
        var date = moment(data[4], "YYYY/MM/DD");
 
        if( (!from.isValid() && !to.isValid()) ||
            (!from.isValid() && date.isSameOrBefore(to) ) ||
            (date.isSameOrAfter(from) && !to.isValid()) ||
            (date.isSameOrAfter(from) && date.isSameOrBefore(to)) )  {
            return true;
        }
        
        return false;
    }
);
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    var table2 = $('#example2').DataTable();
     
    // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
    $('#from, #to').keyup( function() {
        table.draw();
    } );
} );
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>

<table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" border="0">
<tbody><tr>
  <td>From date:</td>
  <td><input type="text" id="from" name="from" placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>To date:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="to" name="to" placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
<thead>
  <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Airi Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2012/08/06</td>
      <td>$137,500</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>2010/10/14</td>
      <td>$327,900</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>2009/09/15</td>
      <td>$205,500</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Sonya Frost</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2008/12/13</td>
      <td>$103,600</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Jena Gaines</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2008/12/19</td>
      <td>$90,560</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
      <td>Support Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2013/03/03</td>
      <td>$342,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Charde Marshall</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>36</td>
      <td>2008/10/16</td>
      <td>$470,600</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
      <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>2012/12/18</td>
      <td>$313,500</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>2010/03/17</td>
      <td>$385,750</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Michael Silva</td>
      <td>Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2012/11/27</td>
      <td>$198,500</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Paul Byrd</td>
      <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2010/06/09</td>
      <td>$725,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Gloria Little</td>
      <td>Systems Administrator</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2009/04/10</td>
      <td>$237,500</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Bradley Greer</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>2012/10/13</td>
      <td>$132,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Dai Rios</td>
      <td>Personnel Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>35</td>
      <td>2012/09/26</td>
      <td>$217,500</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
      <td>Development Lead</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2011/09/03</td>
      <td>$345,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Yuri Berry</td>
      <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>2009/06/25</td>
      <td>$675,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Caesar Vance</td>
      <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>2011/12/12</td>
      <td>$106,450</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Doris Wilder</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>Sydney</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2010/09/20</td>
      <td>$85,600</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
      <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/10/09</td>
      <td>$1,200,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>42</td>
      <td>2010/12/22</td>
      <td>$92,575</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>2010/11/14</td>
      <td>$357,650</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>2011/06/07</td>
      <td>$206,850</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Fiona Green</td>
      <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>48</td>
      <td>2010/03/11</td>
      <td>$850,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Shou Itou</td>
      <td>Regional Marketing</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>2011/08/14</td>
      <td>$163,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Michelle House</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Sydney</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2011/06/02</td>
      <td>$95,400</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Suki Burks</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>53</td>
      <td>2009/10/22</td>
      <td>$114,500</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
      <td>Technical Author</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/05/07</td>
      <td>$145,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
      <td>Team Leader</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2008/10/26</td>
      <td>$235,500</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Martena Mccray</td>
      <td>Post-Sales support</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>46</td>
      <td>2011/03/09</td>
      <td>$324,050</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Unity Butler</td>
      <td>Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/12/09</td>
      <td>$85,675</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>51</td>
      <td>2008/12/16</td>
      <td>$164,500</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
      <td>Secretary</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>2010/02/12</td>
      <td>$109,850</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
      <td>Financial Controller</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>62</td>
      <td>2009/02/14</td>
      <td>$452,500</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2008/12/11</td>
      <td>$136,200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
      <td>Director</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>65</td>
      <td>2008/09/26</td>
      <td>$645,750</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Olivia Liang</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2011/02/03</td>
      <td>$234,500</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Bruno Nash</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>38</td>
      <td>2011/05/03</td>
      <td>$163,500</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2009/08/19</td>
      <td>$139,575</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Thor Walton</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2013/08/11</td>
      <td>$98,540</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Finn Camacho</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/07/07</td>
      <td>$87,500</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
      <td>Data Coordinator</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2012/04/09</td>
      <td>$138,575</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2010/01/04</td>
      <td>$125,250</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>2012/06/01</td>
      <td>$115,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
      <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>2013/02/01</td>
      <td>$75,650</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Cara Stevens</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>46</td>
      <td>2011/12/06</td>
      <td>$145,600</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Hermione Butler</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2011/03/21</td>
      <td>$356,250</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Lael Greer</td>
      <td>Systems Administrator</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>2009/02/27</td>
      <td>$103,500</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2010/07/14</td>
      <td>$86,500</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Shad Decker</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>51</td>
      <td>2008/11/13</td>
      <td>$183,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Michael Bruce</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>2011/06/27</td>
      <td>$183,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
  </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<h3 style="text-align: center;">DATATABLE 2</h3>
<br>
<table id="example2" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011/07/25</td>
        <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2009/01/12</td>
        <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
        <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2012/03/29</td>
        <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Airi Satou</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>2008/11/28</td>
        <td>$162,700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2012/12/02</td>
        <td>$372,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>2012/08/06</td>
        <td>$137,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>2010/10/14</td>
        <td>$327,900</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>39</td>
        <td>2009/09/15</td>
        <td>$205,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sonya Frost</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>2008/12/13</td>
        <td>$103,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jena Gaines</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2008/12/19</td>
        <td>$90,560</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
        <td>Support Lead</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2013/03/03</td>
        <td>$342,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Charde Marshall</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>36</td>
        <td>2008/10/16</td>
        <td>$470,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
        <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>2012/12/18</td>
        <td>$313,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>2010/03/17</td>
        <td>$385,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Michael Silva</td>
        <td>Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2012/11/27</td>
        <td>$198,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Paul Byrd</td>
        <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>2010/06/09</td>
        <td>$725,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Gloria Little</td>
        <td>Systems Administrator</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>2009/04/10</td>
        <td>$237,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bradley Greer</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>41</td>
        <td>2012/10/13</td>
        <td>$132,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Dai Rios</td>
        <td>Personnel Lead</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>35</td>
        <td>2012/09/26</td>
        <td>$217,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
        <td>Development Lead</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2011/09/03</td>
        <td>$345,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Yuri Berry</td>
        <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>2009/06/25</td>
        <td>$675,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Caesar Vance</td>
        <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>2011/12/12</td>
        <td>$106,450</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Doris Wilder</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>Sydney</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>2010/09/20</td>
        <td>$85,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
        <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2009/10/09</td>
        <td>$1,200,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>42</td>
        <td>2010/12/22</td>
        <td>$92,575</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>28</td>
        <td>2010/11/14</td>
        <td>$357,650</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>28</td>
        <td>2011/06/07</td>
        <td>$206,850</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Fiona Green</td>
        <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>48</td>
        <td>2010/03/11</td>
        <td>$850,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Shou Itou</td>
        <td>Regional Marketing</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>2011/08/14</td>
        <td>$163,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Michelle House</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>Sydney</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>2011/06/02</td>
        <td>$95,400</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Suki Burks</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>53</td>
        <td>2009/10/22</td>
        <td>$114,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
        <td>Technical Author</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>2011/05/07</td>
        <td>$145,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
        <td>Team Leader</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2008/10/26</td>
        <td>$235,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Martena Mccray</td>
        <td>Post-Sales support</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>46</td>
        <td>2011/03/09</td>
        <td>$324,050</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Unity Butler</td>
        <td>Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2009/12/09</td>
        <td>$85,675</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>51</td>
        <td>2008/12/16</td>
        <td>$164,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
        <td>Secretary</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>41</td>
        <td>2010/02/12</td>
        <td>$109,850</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
        <td>Financial Controller</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>62</td>
        <td>2009/02/14</td>
        <td>$452,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>2008/12/11</td>
        <td>$136,200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
        <td>Director</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>2008/09/26</td>
        <td>$645,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Olivia Liang</td>
        <td>Support Engineer</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>2011/02/03</td>
        <td>$234,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bruno Nash</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>38</td>
        <td>2011/05/03</td>
        <td>$163,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
        <td>Support Engineer</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>2009/08/19</td>
        <td>$139,575</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Thor Walton</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2013/08/11</td>
        <td>$98,540</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Finn Camacho</td>
        <td>Support Engineer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2009/07/07</td>
        <td>$87,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
        <td>Data Coordinator</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>2012/04/09</td>
        <td>$138,575</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2010/01/04</td>
        <td>$125,250</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>56</td>
        <td>2012/06/01</td>
        <td>$115,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
        <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>2013/02/01</td>
        <td>$75,650</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cara Stevens</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>46</td>
        <td>2011/12/06</td>
        <td>$145,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hermione Butler</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2011/03/21</td>
        <td>$356,250</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Lael Greer</td>
        <td>Systems Administrator</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>2009/02/27</td>
        <td>$103,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2010/07/14</td>
        <td>$86,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Shad Decker</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>51</td>
        <td>2008/11/13</td>
        <td>$183,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Michael Bruce</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>29</td>
        <td>2011/06/27</td>
        <td>$183,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Donna Snider</td>
        <td>Customer Support</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>2011/01/25</td>
        <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```